# Invalid identifier for named pipe ... "not a valid identifier"

Tags: bash, named-pipes

I have the following call to create a named pipe:

```
mkfifo "$HOME/.quicklock/ql_named_pipe";
```

then I read from the named pipe:

```
while read line; do ql_on_named_pipe_msg "$line" "$$"; done < "$HOME/.quicklock/ql_named_pipe" &
```

but I get this error message:

> ./scripts/tsc.sh: line 23: read:
>   `/Users/alexamil/.quicklock/ql_named_pipe': not a valid identifier

anyone know why that shouldn't work?

Comment: Is that `while` loop all of line 23 in your script?

Comment: I think it was actually another line my code that was causing the error, not sure exactly

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you can't show us exactly which line is causing the trouble?  Use `sh -x` or `bash -x` to run the script and find out exactly which line is causing the trouble — I'm 99% sure it isn't that one!  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and remember that if you show an error from 'line 23', there'd better be at least 23 lines of shell script visible, or a very good explanation that the error message says that despite there being just N lines (N < 23) in the script.

Comment: yeah I dunno sometimes computers are confusing lol sorry

Comment: I added an "answer" it might help someone so

Comment: I agree that using a variable to hold the file name is a good idea.  I don't agree that it explains the original problem — at least, not yet.

Comment: yeah I think it was a piece of code that I thought I had commented out above that was very similar to the new code and I just hadn't commented it out yet

Comment: here is what it was, it was this `while read line` was actually `while read $my_named pipe`, that's what caused the error...probably not going to help anyone, so leave that out of my answer

Comment: That is a reasonably sane explanation for the message you got.  The script expanded the variable because you put a `$` before it, and `read` tried to interpret the pathname as a variable and objected.  That makes sense.  Of course, it wasn't the code you showed us, which is annoying, but at least `while read $my_named_pipe` explains why you got the 'invalid identifier' message.  Be grateful you had a full path in it.  Had you used `my_named_pipe=bethnal_green`, you wouldn't have got any error, but you wouldn't have got the result you expected either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the comments carefully, it turns out that the original code looked something like:

```
my_named_pipe="$HOME/.quicklock/ql_named_pipe"

…

while read $my_named_pipe
do
    …
done < $my_named_pipe   # This redirection not 100% clearly stated
```

This would indeed lead to the error 'invalid identifier'.  The `read` command expects to be given variable names as arguments.  When given the `$my_named_pipe`, it sees:

```
while read /Users/whoever/.quicklock/ql_named_pipe
```

and that most definitely is *not* a valid variable name.

As proposed in the [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49091693/15168), a mostly reasonable alternative is:

```
while read line
do
    …
done < $my_named_pipe
```

The 'mostly' is there because there are issues with [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) in the POSIX [`sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) — see also the Bash manual for [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read).  You might prefer to use `read -r` (or there again, maybe you wouldn't).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem was, but this should work fine:

```
my_named_pipe="/some/path/on/your/fs/ql_named_pipe"
while read line; do ql_on_named_pipe_msg "$line" "$$"; done < ${my_named_pipe} &
```